# Cloud Function Query Pricing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i have a question regard to Firebase Cloud Function query pricing. If i use Queries in Cloud Function to Build a new Document and limit it to a maximum of 150 documents. And the Function is triggered on Create of a document. Do i have to pay everytime for 150 reads or just when the last query is older than 30 Minutes.

Comment: Where are you getting 30 minutes from?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions are stateless. Most likely (it depends on the exact calling pattern and your code) you will indeed to pay for all documents in the query every time the code gets invoked.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. This is what i already thought. So it is better to make a query on each mobile device?

Comment: That depends on many factors. But in general I try to not use Cloud Functions as a proxy for a database that is as mobile-focused as Firestore.